# Is it possible to edit .Config file using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, web-config, edit

Here some part of the .config file that I have:

```
    <cs.components>
          <clear/>
          <cs.component name="Security"/>
            <cs.configitems>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.server.name" value="some_name" type="String" description=""/>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.server.database" value="DB_name" type="String" description=""/>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.user" value="user_name" type="String" description=""/>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.pass" value="pass" type="String" description=""/>
    </cs.components>
```

So basically i want to edit the file with corresponding names*
*some_name = server 1; DB_name=A real database on Server 1 and so on... 
Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Where is the input coming from? Meaning where is some_name and DB_name defined? Assuming there are multiple config files, otherwise you wouldn't need to script it. Any text editor with find/replace would suffice.

Comment: Batch files need to be talked to very, very nicely in order to do text-editing. They really, really don't like doing so. Whether it is even possible can depend on many things. Much more detail is required, and virtually all approaches will have some problems. For instnce, is this data all on one line? There's a limit of ~8K on line length. Substituting certain characters could be a problem. Could the file be formatted on multiple lines - a template to be modified, perhaps?

Comment: On what position do you want to add the real names? Behind `description` ?

Comment: the web.config file is just one file. I know its location. I want to use same file BUT edited with correct values of corresponding cs.configitem... so basically i want to SET the "values" assuming that will not always know what is current value... May be my example was a bit confusing and not so well explained..

Answer (score 2):

The Batch file below is a preliminary version of a program that achieve what you want. The names of input and output files are hardcoded in the program, but this can be changed to give them in parameters or to automatically process all files selected by a wild-card. The program delete empty lines and fail if the file contain exclamation marks, but these limitations may be fixed if needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Save replacement strings
set i=0
:nextParam
   if "%~1" equ "" goto endParams
   set /A i+=1
   set "replace[!i!]=%~1"
   shift
goto nextParam
:endParams

rem Process the file
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
      for /F "delims=" %%r in ("!replace[%%i]!") do (
         set "line=!line:%%r!"
      )
   )
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
```

To use this program, give the replacement strings enclosed in quotes as parameters. For example:

```
replace.bat "some_name=server 1" "DB_name=A real database on Server 1"
```

Output:

```
<cs.components>
          <clear/>
          <cs.component name="Security"/>
            <cs.configitems>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.server.name" value="server 1" type="String" description=""/>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.server.database" value="A real database on Server 1" type="String" description=""/>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.user" value="user_name" type="String" description=""/>
              <cs.configitem name="sql.pass" value="pass" type="String" description=""/>
    </cs.components>
```

Comment: Well first of all a really 10x you :) but when i try it, it occurs me that i will not know the "values"... so is there any other option that i first find "sql.server.name" and then i SET its value, becouse in most of the cases i will use it i will not know whats in the file itslef.... I will really be thankfull if there is onother way to do so...

Comment: I don't  understand. Do you want to change a value that you not know what it is? Perhaps if you _explain_ us the way to solve your problem we may _write_ a program to do that, but don't ask us to _guess_ what your problem is!

Comment: <cs.configitem name="sql.server.name" value="old value" type="String" description=""/>
well I want to edit the above with:
<cs.configitem name="sql.server.name" value="newValue" type="String" description=""/>
BUT keep in mind that i do not know for example that value= (is) old Value...
Is it possible to set it not knowing what stands there before the edit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my FindandReplace.cmd script. It uses VBScript to overcome the limitations that Batch imposes. Call it like this `FindAndReplace <searchstring> <replacestring> <filename or Wildcard>` it is case sensitive. After you make the batch file, you would call it like this:

```
   FindAndReplace some_name some_new_name *.config
   FindAndReplace DB_name DB_new_name *.config


::FindAndReplace.cmd
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %~3 /b /a-d /on') do (
 pushd %~dp0
 if not exist _.vbs goto :MakeReplace
 <%%a cscript /nologo _.vbs "%~1" "%~2" "%~3">new.txt
 move /Y new.txt %%~nxa > NUL
 popd
)
del _.vbs
goto :eof

:MakeReplace
 >_.vbs echo Wscript.StdOut.Write Replace(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll,Wscript.arguments(0), Wscript.arguments(1))
```