# Windows cmd/batch - Edit .cfg file where text = something

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need some help with a batch file that runs through Windows Task Scheduler every 6 hours, and I want it to each time the task is run, change a line that pretty much looks like this:

> hostname = "Sometextandnumbers [GMT+4] Sometextandnumbers";

and I want to add 6 hours to the GMT+4 each time the task is run until it goes back to GMT+4 (GMT+4 to GMT+10 to GMT-4 to GMT-10 to GMT+4). The problem is though, I have no clue how to do that in windows cmd or any other program. 
I have Notepad++ installed so if there are any way to utilize that from CMD it could work.
Thanks in advance! Regards, Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Save replacement strings
set i=0
:nextParam
   if "%~1" equ "" goto endParams
   set /A i+=1
   set "replace[!i!]=%~1"
   shift
goto nextParam
:endParams

rem Process the file
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
      for /F "delims=" %%r in ("!replace[%%i]!") do (
         set "line=!line:%%r!"
      )
   )
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
```

To use this program, give the replacement strings enclosed in quotes as parameters. For example:

```
"Sometextandnumbers [GMT+4] Sometextandnumbers=Sometextandnumbers [GMT+10] Sometextandnumbers"
```

thanks [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16469670/2098699)